# Ubuntu 22.04 on Hyper-V: missing RAM

Tags: virtualization, ram, hyper-v

**Update**: Since it seems like I'm not the only one curious about this (got me another curious badge), we clarified the root cause: the Ubuntu VM inherits the reserved (GPU) memory from the Hyper-V host. But **why**? E.g. Fedora and Debian show the same issue, but Windows VMs don't, even with a GUI and my Debian / Ubuntu / Fedora VMs don't have a GUI (Fedora has Cockpit but that's web-based).

Is it that Linux Developers go like "don't care about Hyper-V" and also "fu** MS" or is Microsoft hiding some "secret sauce" from Linux Devs, even though they've become more open during the last decade?

Also @ChanganAuto : if you're running a dozen Linux VMs on limited hardware, it becomes an issue.

I've also [asked](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/939195/linux-vms-and-reserved-memory-on-hyper-v.html) on MS Q&A about this.
**/Update**

I'm running Ubuntu servers on Hyper-V (W10 and 2019) and have assigned them static memory, say 1GiB. Hyper-V Manager confirms that and the host actually uses 1GiB of RAM. But inside the Ubuntu VM free memory is shown as ~839MiB (value fluctuates slightly) by `free`, `top` and `/proc/meminfo`. But `dmidecode -t 17` and `lshw -c memory` show the full 1GiB. Which is to be trusted here?

*Note:* This is my Home-lab and I run Hyper-V on laptop/desktop hardware with CPU-integrated Graphics. So my Hyper-V hosts show a certain amount of memory as "hardware reserved", which is mainly GPU memory. And the missing RAM in the VMs amounts to roughly the "hardware reserved" memory on the hosts. I only run servers, so no GUI. But maybe this could be the issue? If so how do I solve it?

Comment: Not an issue and it's indeed reserved memory.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Why is it not an issue? Also: thanks for clarifying the cause.